# How to read values from a CV_16FC4 matrix

Tags: opencv

How to read values from a CV_16FC4 matrix?
For example, here how i read from a CV_32FC4:

```
        {
            // Create the matrix.
            cv::Mat RGBA32F = cv::Mat(16, 16, CV_32FC4);
            // Read first value.
            const cv::Vec4f color = RGBA32F.at<cv::Vec4f>(0, 0);
        }
```

For CV_16FC4 it would be like:

```
        {
            cv::Mat RGBA16F = cv::Mat(16, 16, CV_16FC4);
            const /*DataType*/ color = RGBA16F.at</* DataType*/>(0, 0);
        }
```

I don't know what to put for DataType. I am using OpenCV 4.6.0.

Thank you!

Comment: does your compiler even have a **half-precision float** type for you to use in plain C++ code? are you SURE your data is half-precision float? -- OpenCV `cv::Mat` does not (yet) have `CV_16F`. that's planned for a future release. you could look around in the `dnn` module of OpenCV. that probably has some half-float conversion routines -- https://github.com/opencv/opencv/wiki/OE-10.-FP16 -- https://github.com/opencv/opencv/pull/12463

Comment: Yes the data is half float. In facts i am using a denoising library from Nvidia called NRD.
The input data the library use must be half float. This is supported on DirectX12 via the DXGI_FORMAT_R16G16B16A16_FLOAT format. So i need an equivalent CPP side, ideally with OpenCV which i use as image library.

Comment: If i understand well the CV_16FC4 type is declared but not ready for use?

Comment: I may have been mistaken. the commit is from 2018 and it includes a definition for `CV_16FC4`. I don't see support for it in the python bindings, so I assumed it wasn't ready. perhaps it is. regardless, you'll have trouble using `Mat::at<T>()` because your *compiler* has to have an appropriate type to access the data (return value), i.e. `float16_t`. there appears to ben opaque `float16_t` provided by OpenCV: https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/df/dc9/classcv_1_1float16__t.html that decays to `float` during access